# How does function composition (.) work from within?

Tags: haskell, lambda, syntax, function-composition

I am studying Haskell. Currently, I am studying function composition. I understand (at least on a basic level) how function `(.)` can be used, but there are two things to it that I understand not.

So the function looks as follows:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
f . g = \x -> f (g x)
```

First, the type declaration. `(b -> c) -> (a -> b)` essentially means that function `f` takes an argument from resulting value (`b`) of function `g` (which takes value `a`) and returns value of type `c`. I don't understand the following part `-> a -> c`, why should there be `-> a` there? Why is `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> c` wrong? From my point of view (which is obviously wrong), function `g` is already taking `a` as an argument.

Second, the body of the function `f . g = \x -> f (g x)`. What does `\x ->` do here? Lambda is pretty straightforward. For example `filter (\(a,b) -> a + b > 4) [(1,2),(3,4)]`, but a simple `\x ->` makes me stuck. I would probably write the body like this `f . (g x) = f (g x)` (which is obviously wrong again).

Comment: Maybe it's easier to read that type as `(.) :: Fun1 -> Fun2 -> Fun3`, i.e. `(.)` takes an argument of type `Fun1` (a function), then another argument of type `Fun2` (another function), and returns a value of type `Fun3` (yet another function, the "composed" one). Concretely, `Fun1 = (b->c)`, `Fun2=(a->b)`, and `Fun3 = (a->c)`. Indeed, you can add parentheses around `a->c` in your type -- they are implicit.

Comment: to your syntactical question, there is no `\ x ->` on its own; there's an implied pair of parentheses there that go to the right as far as possible, so `f . g = \ x -> f (g x)` is actually `f . g = (\ x -> f (g x) )`, a lambda (notation for a) function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> c` would be a function that takes two functions `f :: b -> c` and `g :: a -> b`, and somehow call `g` without an initial argument of type `a`.

For the second question, consider how you would define `(.)` using prefix notation instead. (It might be easier to see if we use a "regular" name for the function; I'll include that as a comment after each snippet of code):

```
(.) f g x = f (g x)    -- compose f g x = f (g x)
```

`x` is the "third argument" for `(.)`, or more precisely the argument for the function returned by `(.) f g`. This is equivalent to defining `(.) f g` as a function directly, by putting a function on the right-hand side instead of the ultimate return value of that function:

```
(.) f g x =       f (g x)  -- Implicit function def: compose f g x =       f (g x)
(.) f g   = \x -> f (g x)  -- Explicit function def: compose f g   = \x -> f (g x)
```

You can also use parentheses to define the function implicitly:

```
(f . g) x = f (g x)
```

Comment: The reason it's defined using an explicit lambda has to do with fine details of program optimization in the GHC compiler. You definitely don't have to worry about that stuff as a beginner, but it's helpful that the people writing critical library functions *do* think about it so your code goes faster.